# Error : application requires permission

Tags: java, android, facebook, permissions

I wanted to create a facebook application for android. I followed the link on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android. After  I launch the application I got the folowing error  = Application requires permission to access the internet.
I have given the permission in the android manifest file using android.permission.INTERNET. How should I fix it?

Comment: Please show us your manifest file. My guess would be that you have misplaced the permission.

Comment: add android.permission.INTERNET in your menifest.xml file

Comment: Please try to clean and build may be "Built Automatically" disable.

Comment: As David mentioned, edit the question and paste your Android Manifest file.

Answer (score 1):

i think there are problem with permission of Internet :: you can following by this way
Goto package explorer  >> open  `AndroidManifest.xml` file and follow : 
First step ::

[image]

**Second step ::**

[image]

press ok and save ::

Comment: Thanks for giving the detailed picture. But it's strange that android permission already exists on my manifest, and I have  checked it was there. The permission is also correctly placed according to the source web i got. Is there something I could do? thx

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in your application Manifest file to access Internet